# Type 'AuthService' has no member 'setUserinformation'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4, firebase-storage

I am finding it difficult to solve an issue of storing data onto my Firebase console. I believe the code is somewhat right, but I cannot seem to figure out the error

> Type 'AuthService' has no member 'setUserinformation'

Hopefully someone can help me with my problem. Your help is greatly appreciated!

I have also attached a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

```
  static func signUp(username: String, email: String, password: String, firstname: String, lastname: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authData: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            onError(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        let uid = authData!.user.uid
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("profile_image").child(uid)

        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (_, error: Error?) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url: URL?, error: Error?) in
                    if let profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
                        self.setUserInformation(profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl, username: username, email: email, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, uid: uid, onSuccess: onSuccess)



                        let ref = Database.database().reference()
                        let usersReference = ref.child("users")

                        let newUserReference = usersReference.child(uid)


                    newUserReference.setValue(["username": username,"firstname": firstname, "lastname": lastname,"email": email, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl])
                        onSuccess()

                    }
                 }
             })
         })
    func setUserInformation(profileImageUrl: String, username: String, email: String, firstname: String, lastname: String, uid: String, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let usersReference = ref.child("users")
        let newUserReference = usersReference.child(uid)
        newUserReference.setValue(["username": username,"firstname": firstname, "lastname": lastname,"email": email, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl])
        onSuccess()
     }  
 }
```

Comment: I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708720/cannot-store-firebase-data-type-authservice-has-no-member-setuserinformation/52709310#52709310