# Cannot store firebase data Type 'AuthService' has no member 'setUserinformation'

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I am finding it difficult to solve an issue of storing data onto my Firebase console. I believe the code is somewhat right, but I cannot seem to figure out the error

Type 'AuthService' has no member 'setUserinformation'

Hopefully someone can help me with my problem. Your help is greatly appreciated!

I have also attached a screenshot of the problem: [screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwlTm.png)

```
static func signUp(username: String, email: String, password: String, firstname: String, lastname: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authData: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            onError(error?.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        let uid = authData!.user.uid
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("profile_image").child(uid)

        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (_, error: Error?) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url: URL?, error: Error?) in
                if let profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {

                    self.setUserInformation(profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl!, username: username, email: email, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, uid: uid, onSuccess: onSuccess)
                }

              }

            )}

        )}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called a class method (**setUserInformation**) in a static method (**signUp**) which is not allowed and the **self** object didn't create while you called it.

You can resolve it by adding a **static** to the **setUserInformation** method or removing **static** from **signUp** method.

Comment: Thank you! I added the static to the setUserInformation